# How to prevent duplicate submit

Tags: apex, visualforce, marketing-cloud, email-template, survey

On SFMC I created an email template that includes the degree of customer satisfaction from 0 to 10. Clicking on a number you are redirected to a visualforce page to submit the vote. If I try to click the first time on an "x" vote, and then reopen the email by clicking on a "y" vote, I noticed that 2 records are created on salesforce with the same contact but with two different votes. How could I solve the problem by putting a block on the second vote for example? Each contact should be able to cast only one vote.
Should we act on the marketing cloud side with a block on voting in the email or on the salesforce side visualforce page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Once an email is rendered and sent, you have very limited control over what's displayed etc., so your logic will have to be on the processing page.

The following will be much easier with Cloudpages (due to the built-in encryption / decryption mechanisms)  than visualforce, but let's just skip that for now and keep the solution design abstract, as you might have other reasons for your choice of framework.

So:
The link you use to access your page should be identifying the source uniquely. The source is an email sendout event. Which means a combination of a recipient (subscriberkey) and the email sent (jobid), plus two technical parameters that ensure there are no duplicates under any circumstance (ListId and BatchId)
Use those 4 as an identifier to block duplicate subscriptions from the same email send event.

From your email, send the following parameters to your page - you might want to encrypt them (easy with Cloudpages):

%%_SubscriberKey%%, %%JobId%%, %%ListId%%, %%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%

You can leverage SFMC standard capabilities here, reference:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

These four things together identify a unique send event.
Store them next to your vote in your presumed "votes" object, separately or in a concatenated fashion like subscriberkey-jobid-listId-batchid.

Then, on your page:

- retrieve the incoming parameters from the link
- (decrypt them)
- retrieve all records in your "votes" object where the (concatenated) ID == the incoming (concatenated) Id
- if 0 are found: count the vote
- else: display error, do not count the vote

hope this helps!